# NSManagedObject property isn't being set correctly when initialized

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a Core Date object that I am creating in the convenience init of one of my secondary views. This init is being run when I load the application (which I don't understand since the view isn't showing, but that isn't really the problem).

My problem is that a property, `locations`, on my core data object is returning `Optional(Set([]))` while loading the application. This then assigns `Optional(Set([]))` to the @Published property in the initializer. Then when I compare the two later on, @Published = `Optional(Set([]))` and `locations = nil`.

```
WorkItemViewModel.swift

@Published var locations: Set<Location>?

convenience init(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let childObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    childObjectContext.parent = viewContext
    self.init(workItem: WorkItem(insertIntoManagedObjectContext: childObjectContext), viewContext: viewContext)
}

init(workItem: WorkItem, viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    self.viewContext = viewContext
    self.workItem = workItem
    self.locations = workItem.locations
}
```

As you can see, i'm creating the object on a child context so it doesn't show up in other views.

This convenience init creates the object and is then calling the regular init, which loads up @Published properties with information related to the object.

I've also created a convenience init inside the actual object that i'm calling to create the object and load it with default values. This is where i'm setting `locations` to nil:

```
WorkItem+CoreDataClass.swift

// wrapper around the actual property to easily set it
var locations: Set<Location>? {
    get { return locationsValue as? Set<Location> }
    set { locationsValue = newValue as NSSet? }
}

convenience init(title: String = "", category: CategoryType = .general, dueDate: Date = Date(), frequency: FrequencyType = .oneTime, locations: Set<Location>? = nil, notes: String = "", insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity( forEntityName: "WorkItem", in: context)!
    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    self.title = title
    self.category = category
    self.dueDate = dueDate
    self.frequency = frequency
    self.locations = locations
    self.notes = notes
}
```

I'm not sure whats going on here. I know I can default the @Published property with nil in the view model, but I'd like to keep the default values all in one place on the object.

I've checked and the actual locations property isn't being set to nil until I load the view.

so in other words:

load app -> view init runs -> object property sets @published property to `Optional(Set([]))` -> show view -> object property is set to `nil`

Comment: Maybe one way to handle this better is to make the wrapper property non-optional so that you always work with an empty set?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that your `childObjectContext` exists only within the scope of the init code.  Once the init has finished, the `childObjectContext` is destroyed, together with all the information it holds about the objects registered with it.  Hence your object’s properties revert to nil.

Keep a reference to the `childObjectContext` as a var in WorkItemViewModel.